# Bizarre PG::UndefinedTable Error with Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I built an app with Rails that scrapes twitter for phone numbers. It's up on heroku, and it was running fine until I added a model for different guests using the app. Now whenever I attempt to db:migrate, db:reset, or db:create, I am getting the error "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "guests" does not exist". I have read every stack overflow article on this topic, but every solution uses commands that I can't run without getting the error.

Everything with the program worked great locally. I could migrate to the database, drop and recreate it if I needed to, and use the app to its full functionality. The issue was in migrating to the postgres Heroku database. I pushed to Heroku without any errors, but when I tried to run the app online, it told me it couldn't access its database. I went to migrate my database changes to Heroku, and when I did, I got the error. I tried resetting the Heroku database and migrating again, but I got the same error on migration.

Guest is a model that I created when I added sign in to the app. Users are twitter accounts, and Guests are people logged in with the scraper. Users belong to guests via a "has_many" "belongs_to" relation.

Also, after getting the error with heroku, when I try to migrate to my local database, I get the error. Like I said, I can't db:reset, db:create, or db:migrate locally any more. I can only db:drop.

I use postgres locally as well as in production. My tables all look good. I have checked the timestamps on my migration files and tried creating guests first and creating users first. Here's a screenshot of my [schema file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VZWt.png).

This is a screenshot of my [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvPPr.jpg).

Any help is hugely appreciated. I have been stuck on this for a week.

Comment: Is there a stack trace to go with that error? Sounds like something is trying to instantiate a `Guest` or lookup the `Guest` class structure while the app is setting itself up to run `db:migrate`.

Comment: What exactly is a stack trace? And how would I find that?

Comment: The exception should come with list of the method calls so that you can see the path that triggered the exception. This should be in your logs or on the standard error output.

Comment: http://imgur.com/WWDZD5Q is the error output from my terminal. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, you're probably better off pasting that into your question as text before someone complains about it. What is `config/initializes/ApiLoader.rb` all about and why is it doing a `Guest.where(...).exists?` query?

Comment: That file loads API tokens and gets access rights for the calls I'm going to make. It also creates a null guest, though, for the case where the guest of the site doesn't log in. The exists? call is there to make sure the null guest isnt created twice.

Comment: Can I not reference the guest class in an initializer file? That seems like it could be what's wrong. But if so, why would it work before trying to migrate to heroku?

Comment: Probably worked before Heroku because you had the `guests` table in your database before you added `ApiLoader.rb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT

Thanks a ton, mu is too short. I think my issue was that I was referencing my guest class in my initializer file. I moved that bit of code to the controller method that it was relevant to, pushed to heroku, and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Right. If you try to `Guest.where(...)` then AR will query the database to see what `Guest` looks like, that's the funny looking `::regclass` query you saw in the stack trace. But if there is no `guests` table in the database (i.e. the migration hasn't run yet) then the `'"guests"'::regclass` type cast will fail and you end up with a `PG::UndefinedTable` error. Initializers shouldn't reference the database: doing so results in these dependency loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your postgres user doesnt have permission to create or drop databases, you need to use pg:reset

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
```

[This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#using-the-cli) is what I followed and it worked for me.

Comment: I have tried this, and it doesn't change anything for me